# GAE urlfetch Host header set to IP address instead of hostname

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I am calling a third party web service from app engine. This particular service is picky. I ran into an issue where calls would work fine for a while, then stop working, then start working again. I realized that if I manually stopped all instances in the admin console, that the calls would work again.

I setup a proxy to route the calls through that so I could see the headers and all detail. I think I have tracked the issue down to the following. After an instance has been up for a while (the app usually just needs 1 to 3 instances right now) app engine will start using the IP address of the destination as the value for the host header instead of the hostname. Well the service doesn't like that. Whether it *should* care is another matter.

So my question is, why does app engine use the ip address for the host header eventually instead of the hostname? And, of course, is there anything I can do about it? I know that I cannot set the host header, but maybe there is something else that can be done.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for finding this behavior.  We have had intermittent issues with urlfetch for a long time, and will try to detect if this is the issue.

One thing you could try is to target a specific instance/module:

`http://instance.version.module.app-id.appspot.com`

and cycle through the instances.  If you just target the module, it will kill the instance after some inactivity.  So, perhaps that would not trigger the GAE DNS shortcut.

Another trick would be to add a fake, random, query string after your url: `?foo=D7hfka67h`.  Perhaps that would prevent GAE from recognizing the repeat url, and trying to shortcut the DNS.